# Elastic search wild card search

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have used string array to index the field as below:

```
public class MetaData
{
    public string[] time { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}


client.CreateIndex(casedirectory_metadata, c => c
    AddMapping<object>(m => m
        .Properties(props => props
            .String(ps => ps.Name("time").IndexAnalyzer("keyword"))
            .String(ps => ps.Name("name").IndexAnalyzer("keyword"))
)));

MetaData objmetadata = new MetaData();
objmetadata.time = new string[] { "morning" };
objmetadata.name = "jhon";
client.Index<object>((object)objmetadata);

MetaData objmetadata = new MetaData();
objmetadata.time = new string[] {"this morning", "9.30 am", "evening" };
objmetadata.name = "jhon rapher";
client.Index<object>((object)objmetadata);
```

In the above code there are two fields indexed time and name.
Time field is of string array type and name field if of simple string type
In Below code wild card characters search is performed with Aggregations on time field

```
var qryRes1 = client.Search<object>(x => x

                    .Aggregations(ag => ag
                           .Filter("filter", (flt => flt
                               .Filter(f =>
                               {
                                   FilterContainer filter = null;
                                   filter &= f.Query(qr => qr.Wildcard(wl => wl.OnField("time").Value("morning")));
                                   return filter;
                               })
                                      .Aggregations(agr => agr

                                       .Terms("time", tr =>
                                       {
                                           TermsAggregationDescriptor<object> trmAggDescriptor = new TermsAggregationDescriptor<object>();
                                           trmAggDescriptor.Field("time");

                                           trmAggDescriptor.Size(0);
                                           return trmAggDescriptor;
                                       }))))
                         ));
```

above  query should return only Aggregations for "morning" with count 1 because first "morning" is filtered out using wildcard and then Aggregations is applied but it aggregates and returns all the values in time filed.If the same query is applied for field name ="john" it's returning correct result 1 record.

Do I have to do anything else to do wild card search on array type field?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why your query is returning both records.  It seems to me that the query should in fact only return the first record.  That being said, I think you should try making the "time" field not analyzed.  Why are you using the keyword analyzer on that field (as opposed to making it not analyzed)?

Comment: @dogjones thanks for the reply.Please check the above edited code is what i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it myself.I had to use include and exclude in Aggregations to make filter work and remove wild card type query.Refering [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values) helped me